# Is it possible to view exactly what a package will install and where?

Tags: package-management

If I want to install the tomcat6 package for example, would it be possible to see a list of files/directories of what/where this package will save?

Also, can I see the actual debian package to learn from it?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the package information at packages.ubuntu.com (e.g. [tomcat6](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/tomcat6)), including file lists and download link.

Answer (score 1):

First, download the package you're interested in:

`apt-get download tomcat6`

Then open the downloaded package with File Roller to inspect it's contents:

`file-roller tomcat6*.deb`

Comment: after downloading, you can use 'dpkg -c <pkg>.deb' to display the contents of the package without needing to extract it. I usually pipe to less to make it easier to navigate the contents, like this: dpgk -c mypkg.deb | less

Comment: I prefer to use file roller because you can inspect the control files and maintainer scripts.

Installing a package can do more than copy files :)

Answer (score 0):

If package is already installed:

You can see what files from <packagename> are installed to your system by typing:

```
dpkg-query -L <packagename>
```

Without installing package:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get install -d <packagename>

for file in /var/cache/apt/archives/*; do
dpkg-deb -c $file;
done
```

This clears your local apt cache, then downloads the package without installing it.
Then it prints the contents of the package and yet-to-be-installed dependencies to the screen.  You might prefer

```
dpkg-deb -c $file | tee -a <filename>
```

to write the package contents to a file.